# Polymer Getting started template

Tags: web, polymer

Can someone provide me a default polymer template where i can see the structure of it.
I couldn't find a template which has all the features, which i could use for a static mobile app.

Comment: https://www.polymer-project.org/ has examples for all official polymer elements. look @ core-scaffold that will give you a idea of a typical mobile layout.

Comment: [Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html) is a simple explanation about Polymer. There is also a [tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html) available. Other than that, take a look at the [`core-scaffold`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-scaffold) and check out the [`core-animated-pages`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages) to change content depending on the selected item in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a basic scaffold (project structure) then there's a great video by Rob Dodson from polymer team.
PS: You need to know about YEOMAN

Comment: Is there any example template for a website in which polymer is used.. ?

Comment: Im a beginner so I need a template or a starter project .. but i couldn&#39;t find one :/

Comment: I used that but there is not used much controls.

Comment: no such thing as "default polymer template"  as there are @ least 3 or 4 diff ways to do everything in polymer.  https://www.polymer-project.org/ has all the info you should need. read it,  try it, work with the elements a while on a site like http://plnkr.co/ or jsbin.com/ and eventually you will understand.